# error CS1061: Type `BikeCostDetails.Bike' does not contain a definition for `CalculateFinalCost'

Tags: c#, oop

**File - Bike.cs**

```
namespace BikeCostDetails
{
public class Bike
{
    private string bikeName;
    private string bikeType;
    private double bikeCost;
    private double onRoadPrice;

    public string BikeName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bikeName;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bikeName = value;
        }
    }
    public string BikeType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bikeType;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bikeType = value;
        }
    }
    public double BikeCost
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bikeCost;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bikeCost = value;
        }
    }
    public double OnRoadPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.onRoadPrice;
        }
        set
        {
            this.onRoadPrice = value;
        }
    }

    public bool CheckForBikeType(string bikeType)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (bikeType.Equals("naked") || bikeType.Equals("doomed"))
        {
            flag = true;
        }
        return flag;
    }

}
}
```

**file 2 - Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BikeCostDetails
{
public class Program
{

    public static Bike CalculateFinalCost(Bike bike)
    {

        string type = bike.BikeType;
        double cost = bike.BikeCost;
        double finalCost;
        if (type.Equals("naked"))
        {
            finalCost = cost - (cost * 10 / 100);
        }
        else
        {
            finalCost = cost + (cost * 5 / 100);
        }

        bike.OnRoadPrice = finalCost;
        return bike;
    }


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bike b = new Bike();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the bike name");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter bike type");
        string type = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter bike cost");
        double cost = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        b.BikeName = name;
        b.BikeType = type;
        b.BikeCost = cost;

        if (b.CheckForBikeType(type) == true)
        {
            
            Bike bi = b.CalculateFinalCost(b);
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for buying " + name + ". You need to pay the amount of Rs " + bi.OnRoadPrice);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Bike Type");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am getting this error:

**Error CS1061  'Bike' does not contain a definition for 'CalculateFinalCost' and no accessible extension method 'CalculateFinalCost' accepting a first argument of type 'Bike' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Can someone please help me solve this error?? I am new to C#.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the final code. I solved it on the same day I posted the problem. Didn't notice the error first.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BikeCostDetails
{
    public class Bike
    {
        private string bikeName;
        private string bikeType;
        private double bikeCost;
        private double onRoadPrice;
        
        public string BikeName{
          get{
            return this.bikeName;
          }
          set{
            this.bikeName = value;
          }
        }
        public string BikeType{
          get{
            return this.bikeType;
          }
          set{
            this.bikeType = value;
          }
        }
        public double BikeCost{
          get{
            return this.bikeCost;
          }
          set{
            this.bikeCost = value;
          }
        }
        public double OnRoadPrice{
          get{
            return this.onRoadPrice;
          }
          set{
            this.onRoadPrice = value;
          }
        }
        
        public bool CheckForBikeType(string bikeType){
          bool flag = false;
          if(bikeType.Equals("naked") || bikeType.Equals("doomed")){
            flag = true;
          }
          return flag;
        }
    }
        
    
  public class Program{
    
      public Bike CalculateFinalCost(Bike bike){
        
        string type = bike.BikeType;
        double cost = bike.BikeCost;
        double finalCost = 0;

         if(type.Equals("naked")){
            finalCost = cost - (cost * 10/100);
         }
         else{
            finalCost = cost + (cost * 5/100);
         }
        
         bike.OnRoadPrice = finalCost;
         return bike;
      }
    
      
      public static void Main(string[] args){
        Bike b = new Bike();
        Program p = new Program();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the bike name");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter bike type");
        string type = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter bike cost");
        double cost = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        
        b.BikeName = name;
        b.BikeType = type;
        b.BikeCost = cost;

        if(b.CheckForBikeType(type) == true){
          b = p.CalculateFinalCost(b);
          Console.WriteLine("Thank you for buying "+ name+". You need to pay the amount of Rs "+b.OnRoadPrice);
        }
        else{
          Console.WriteLine("Invalid Bike Type");
        }
      }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't instantiate `Program`. Your code (`Main`) is already executing inside the `Program` class. The original approach was actually the proper way, with the change laid out in my answer.

Comment: I tried it but it showed error. So we have to make an object of program class or just call it using Program.CalculateFinalCost(b)

Answer (score 3):

`Bike bi = b.CalculateFinalCost(b);` should just be `Bike bi = CalculateFinalCost(b);` No `b.` before the method name. The error is what it says: the `Bike` type doesn't contain a `CalculateFinalCost` method. That method is defined in your `Program` class.

Comment: I only answered because I wanted to express a different way to do it, your answer is more appropriate for the solution.

Comment: No it should be  Program p = new Program(); b = p.CalculateFinalCost(b);                           I already solved it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change

`public static Bike CalculateFinalCost(Bike bike)`

To

```
public static Bike CalculateFinalCost(this Bike bike)
```

That will allow you to use you method as a part of the class.